# ASP.NET Identify Framework Automatic Login Hook

Tags: asp.net, identity

I have a web app that I started from the Identify 2.0 alpha sample. I contains the identify framework with roles.

If a user checks the box "Remember me" when they log in then the next time they go to the site they are already logged in.

I need to be able to perform some additional checks in my system when the user comes to the site whether they log in at that point or are automatically logged in because they checked that box.

Where can I hook some place that when the user visits the site I can do a process associated with them logging in either automatically or through the login form?

Answer (score 0):

Two ways:

1. Use ASP.NET Session and do your checks in Session_On_Start.
2. Issue a session cookie (not ASP.NET Session, a normal cookie) when the user logs in. On all subsequent visits, check if the session cookie remains. If not, the user closed the browser between the visits.

Both approaches share a fundamental problem that is caused by the way the web works. There really is no way to define when a user leaves a site. If the user closes the tab and then reopens it immediately, that will not cause any of those two methods to fire the initialization routine as the browser will keep the session cookies intact.